# httr GET function read table

Tags: json, r, web-scraping, web, httr

I want to scrape this [website](http://datacenter.mep.gov.cn/report/water/water.jsp?year=2016&wissue=2&x=55&y=15), and get the data from the table.

I use `GET` from the package `httr`, code is like below:

```
url <- 'http://datacenter.mep.gov.cn/report/water/water.jsp?'
year <- 2016
wissue <- 2

res <- GET(url,
           query = list(year = year,
                        wissue = wissue))


resC <- content(res, as = 'text', encoding = 'utf-8')
```

But what I got is not a json string but something very strange like below:

```
"\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<html>\r\n\t<head>\r\n\t\t<title>中华人民共和国环境保护部--政府网站数据中心</title>\r\n\t\t<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html;
```

I wonder is there anyway to parse this format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rowspan` attribute is going to make dealing with this table pretty interesting. You have a few choices, two of which are:

1. use `html_table()` on the target `<table>` using `fill=TRUE` and perform surgery on the resultant data frame
2. attack it at the `<tr>`-level and build the data frame from the ground up

This answer does the latter.

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
```

First, we get the content in a form we can perform XML/HTML surgery on:

```
content(res, as = 'text', encoding = 'utf-8') %>% 
  read_html() -> pg
```

Next, we target and extract the table node with the report:

```
tab <- html_nodes(pg, "table#report1")
```

Here's te tricky bit. We first target all the `<tr>` elements that have `@rowspan` attributes but no `<td>` elements with a `@colspan` attribute:

```
html_nodes(tab, xpath=".//tr[td[not(@colspan) and @rowspan]]") %>%
```

Next, we process those invidivually:

```
  map_df(function(x) {
```

We get the # of rows the `<tr>` spans:

```
    html_nodes(x, xpath=".//td[@rowspan]") %>% 
      html_attr("rowspan") %>% 
      as.numeric() -> row_ct
```

Find all the sibling `<tr>` elements and reduce the set to the remaining ones in this `<tr>` "block":

```
    rows <- html_nodes(x, xpath=".//following-sibling::tr")
    rows <- rows[1:(row_ct-1)]
```

Make a data frame from that first block row

```
    html_nodes(x, xpath=".//td") %>% 
      html_text() %>% 
      setNames(sprintf("X%d", 1:13)) %>% 
      as.list() %>% 
      flatten_df() -> first
```

Go through all filtered sibling rows and do the same, leaving room to fill in the spanned column:

```
    map_df(rows, ~html_nodes(., xpath=".//td") %>% 
             html_text() %>% 
             setNames(c("X1", "X2", sprintf("X%d", 4:13))) %>% 
             as.list()) %>% 
      mutate(X3=first$X3) %>% 
      select(X1, X2, X3, everything()) -> rest

    bind_rows(first, rest)

  }) -> h2o_df

dplyr::glimpse(h2o_df)
```

I can't paste the output of that since SO's javascript text filter is so brain dead it thinks that the post is spam just b/c it has kanji characters.

Here's all the code in a contiguous chunk:

```
tab <- html_nodes(pg, "table#report1") 

html_nodes(tab, xpath=".//tr[td[not(@colspan) and @rowspan]]") %>% 
  map_df(function(x) {

    html_nodes(x, xpath=".//td[@rowspan]") %>% 
      html_attr("rowspan") %>% 
      as.numeric() -> row_ct

    rows <- html_nodes(x, xpath=".//following-sibling::tr")
    rows <- rows[1:(row_ct-1)] 

    html_nodes(x, xpath=".//td") %>% 
      html_text() %>% 
      setNames(sprintf("X%d", 1:13)) %>% 
      as.list() %>% 
      flatten_df() -> first

    map_df(rows, ~html_nodes(., xpath=".//td") %>% 
             html_text() %>% 
             setNames(c("X1", "X2", sprintf("X%d", 4:13))) %>% 
             as.list()) %>% 
      mutate(X3=first$X3) %>% 
      select(X1, X2, X3, everything()) -> rest

    bind_rows(first, rest)

  }) -> h2o_df
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I used `html_table()` before, but usually the function automatically detects the table, but why this time the table I got through `html_table()` is so messy and when I try to write it to a file, it says differing number of rows....could you please tell me how to solve this?

Comment: there's no easy way out of this scraping. the site uses `colspan` and `rowspan` in many `<td>` elements to make the table "pretty" to the user (it's kind of ugly if you ask me) which makes scraping very hard. `html_table()` can make many educated guesses, but it's going to fill in a data frame pretty badly when there are `rowspan`s involved (it's pretty decent with `colspan`s).